# How do I make a boot loader load the existing boot loader from the first partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, mbr, bootloader

I installed ubuntu using wubi and then I tried installing grub 2 but it failed. I need a way to reinstall the mbr sp it will load the windows 7 loader from the first partition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Windows Vista (and later) particularities, but usually booting to Recovery Console and using "fixmbr" helped.

Also you can try to fix grub2 (may be by using of `grub 1` or `grub4dos`) and making it chainload bootloader from the first partition (or NTDLR directly, if `grub4dos` can cope with Vista bootloader).